# Is there a way to use StrictlyEnforceRange with differently sized delegates?

Tags: qt, listview, qml

Code example for problem illustation purposes:

```
import QtQuick 2.15

ListView {
    model: 10
    highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
    preferredHighlightBegin: width / 2 - currentItem.width / 2
    preferredHighlightEnd: width / 2 + currentItem.width / 2
    orientation: Qt.Horizontal
    snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem
    spacing: 15
    delegate: Rectangle {
        width: index === 5 ? 150 : 50
        height: 50
    }
}
```

Positioning view at any other index has smooth animation transition as it should, but when set to 5 (that is where different sized delegate is) it just snaps to it with no animation. Is it the issue within ListView itself? And is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `preferredHighlightBegin` and `preferredHighlightEnd` positions are calculated based on the width of the current item. When the current item changes to an item with a different width, the highlight rect position also needs to be updated to reflect the new width.

One solution may be that you can calculate the `preferredHighlightBegin` and `preferredHighlightEnd` positions based on the total width of the items up to and including the current item. This way, the highlight rect position will be updated whenever the width of any of the previous items changes. The code below may help:

```
import QtQuick 2.15

ListView {
    model: 10
    highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
    orientation: Qt.Horizontal
    snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem
    spacing: 15
    delegate: Rectangle {
        width: index === 5 ? 150 : 50
        height: 50
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        var totalWidth = 0
        for (var i = 0; i <= currentIndex; i++) {
            totalWidth += visualItemModel.get(i).width
        }
        preferredHighlightBegin = width / 2 - totalWidth + visualItemModel.get(currentIndex).width / 2
        preferredHighlightEnd = width / 2 - totalWidth + visualItemModel.get(currentIndex).width / 2
    }
    onCurrentIndexChanged: {
        var totalWidth = 0
        for (var i = 0; i <= currentIndex; i++) {
            totalWidth += visualItemModel.get(i).width
        }
        preferredHighlightBegin = width / 2 - totalWidth + visualItemModel.get(currentIndex).width / 2
        preferredHighlightEnd = width / 2 - totalWidth + visualItemModel.get(currentIndex).width / 2
    }
}
```